# Partitioning scheme: Windows 7 on SSD and Ubuntu 16.04 on HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I would like to know if my current partition scheme is OK, as I am experiencing some HDD and SSD overheating and I have read it could be due to a suboptimal partition.

I have a 250GB SSD where Windows 7 is installed.

Additionally I have a 1TB HDD of which:

- 800GB are media storage (films, music, etc)
- 200GB approx are for Ubuntu 16.04 with the following divisions (in this order):

  - 500MB at `/boot`
  - 20GB at `/var`
  - 20GB at `/home`
  - 16GB of swap (double of my 8GB RAM)
  - 100GB at `/` (root filesystem)

I did this partition a long time ago, and I'm really unsure if this is even remotely right as I do not understand the reasoning behind the need for the partitioning.

Comment: Partition has nothing to do with overheating. And your Ubuntu partitions are for a server setup. Not a problem but if you use it as a desktop rather pointkess.

Comment: /(sysem root) only needs 10-20 GB

Comment: I agree with avery. And personally I would install C: and / on the SSD  (system related files on the SSD) and personal data (d: and a data partition or /home if you use that) on the HDD

Comment: A 10 GB root (`/`) is adequate for a basic installation, but if you install lots of programs or use space outside of the other partitions you've split off, it could be inadequate. Given the amount of disk space available, there's no point in going that low -- but 100 GB is way too big, given separate `/home` and other partitions. A separate `/var` is useful mainly on some types of servers; it's seldom needed on a workstation/desktop/laptop. The key point, though, is that improper partitioning is almost certainly *not* the cause of overheating.

Comment: The only *possible* partitioning problem that might cause performance issues or heat issues might be misaligned partitions. To quick-check this, in `terminal` do `sudo fdisk -l` and see if it indicates alignment issues. For a more detailed check, use `parted` instead.